# Como funciona o atributo android:ems (TextView)

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de entender com que funciona este atributo (`android:ems`).

Vi algo citando que ele age sobre a fonte do texto, mais não entendi de que forma. Tentei fazer alguns testes, e não notei resultado.

Alguém sabe como ele age sobre um `TextView`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `ems` é usado para definir a largura dos componentes com relação a fonte atual, logo seu `TextView` vai ter a largura necessária para mostrar a quantidade de caracteres que você definir usando o `ems`.

Entretanto para surtir efeito é necessário definir o `layout_width` como `wrap_content`, pois os outros tipos de layout sobreescrevem a configuração de largura `ems`.

Comment: Então era por isso, porque meu `layout_width` está definido como `0`, e `layout_weight=1000`, sendo assim um tamanho proporcional ao espaço reservado a ele em relação aos outros componentes _parent_. Sendo assim como você disse não faz nenhum sentido utilizar o atributo `ems`, em meu caso. Certo? Já que não interfere na fonte como eu imagina e sim na largura do componente para suportar uma determinado quantidade de caracteres. Não deixando de ser útil para outros casos.

Comment: @Fernando exatamente, altera a largura do componente se o `layout_width` estiver definido como `wrap_content`

Comment: Essa propriedade então seria bem interessante utilizar em um `EditText`, que por exemplo eu queira que tenha espaço visível para `15` caracteres.

Answer (score 7):

`ems` é uma unidade de comprimento definida em relação à fonte utilizada.
`1em` representa o comprimento da letra `m`.

Quando, por exemplo, num `TextView` é definido o atributo `android:ems="15"` você está limitando o comprimento do TextView a 15 letras `m`.