# Definir largura de um TextView pela quantidade máxima de caracteres

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Estou criando um layout_item para meu ListView, mas quero que todos os elementos estejam alinhados, mas alguns TextView podem ter variação de tamanho (eles assumem o valor de um numeral que pode variar de 0 até 1000) para isso estou atribuindo valores fixos para a largura deles.

O problema e que não sei se o valor que estou atribuindo e o suficiente para todo tipo de tela e gostaria de saber se existe uma forma ou uma dimensão ideal para usar nesse caso.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagem"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bebidas_s_alcool" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amigo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/lista"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lista"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imagem"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imagem"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Nome do Item"
    android:textColor="@color/Texto" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rs"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botaomenos"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:onClick="menos"
        android:src="@drawable/menos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantidade"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="5.55"
        android:textColor="@color/Texto" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:onClick="mais"
        android:src="@drawable/mais" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/valor"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="R$"
    android:textColor="@color/Texto" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/valor"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="5000,00"
    android:textColor="@color/Texto" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Como pode ser visto no layout acima os TextView que e nescessario especificar o tamanho são os ids `quantidade e valor` e a dimensão que estou usando é `sp`

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10620/2541

Answer (score 0):

Especificando a propriedade "layout_width" como "wrap_content" nos dois TextView vai resolver seu problema pois o atributo "wrap_content" serve justamente para isso, ocupar o espaço necessário para exibição completa de um determinado conteúdo.

Comment: O problema e se colocar wrap_contenr os elementos da lista vão ficar desalinhado em relação aos demais pois o tamanho vai variar com o tamanho do texto escrito